# how to prevent onSubmit() function getting called on click of a cancel button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have one angular material dialog box and inside that there is one template driven form. It is working well when I click on submit button however when I click on cancel button then also onSubmit() function is getting called. how to prevent that?
this is my code snippet

```js
// ts file
export class RejectPopupComponent implements OnInit {
   submitted:boolean=false;
  comment: string;
  loanID: string;
  createdDate: string;
  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<RejectPopupComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) {
    this.dataService.loanIdSource.subscribe(loanID => (this.loanID = loanID));
    console.log(this.loanID);

    this.dataService.applicationDateSource.subscribe(
      applicationDate => (this.createdDate = applicationDate)
    );
    console.log(this.loanID, this.createdDate);
  }
 
  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

     onSubmit(form:any){
      console.log('hello')
    console.log(form);
       const statusDecisionInput = { loanID: "", createdDate: "", approverAction: "Rejected", reasonToReject: '' };
   statusDecisionInput.loanID = this.loanID;
   statusDecisionInput.createdDate = this.createdDate;
   statusDecisionInput.reasonToReject = form.reasonToReject;
   console.log(statusDecisionInput);
    this.submitted=true;
  }


  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

```html
 <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)">
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>Why are you rejecting?</p>
    <textarea matInput rows="10" cols="38"  placeholder="Leave a comment" name="reasonToReject" ngModel required></textarea>
  </div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button class="submit-button" type='submit' 
  [disabled]="f.invalid" cdkFocusInitial (click)="onNoClick()">Submit</button> 
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: put `type="button"`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Put `type="button"` explicitly to avoid button trigerring a form submission

```
<button mat-button type="button" (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
```

You can check the spec [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) Note that the default behaviour is `submit` unless specified otherwise.

Comment: I was pulling my hair out on this one. Thanks!

Comment: button `type=submit` by default, you learn something new everyday. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change in template:

```
(click)="onNoClick($event)"
```

Change in component:

```
onNoClick(event:any): void {
  event.stopPropagation();
  ........//Your existing code
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

> To know more about it read : https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: I tried this but still onSubmit() function is getting triggered on click of a cancel button

Comment: In this case you will have to do `preventDefault()` as form submission is the default behaviour which we are trying to prevent. Propogation prevents bubbling only.

Answer (score 0):

In my template, I changed from  `<button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>` to  `<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data"  (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>`
somehow it is preventing onSubmit() function getting called.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `(click)="onClick()"` from cancel button .

This will solve your problem